# Find all solutions of the equation $\cos 4x + \cos x = 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am writing my first university maths exam . I truly have no clue as to how I should proceed. Any tips or methods on how to solve this would greatly appreciated.

Question:

By using the addition formulae show that $$\cos(A + B) + \cos(A - B) = 2 \cos A\cos B$$

Setting $u = A + B$ and $v = A - B$, deduce that $$\cos u + \cos v = 2 \cos\frac{u + v}{2} \cdot \cos \frac{u-v}{2}.$$

Use this to find all solutions of the equation $$\cos 4x + \cos x = 0.$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Some of your characters are not displaying correctly (your minus sign appears as an upside-down exclamation mark: ¡). Please have a look at [this tutorial and reference guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Thank you.Sorry for the editing error just really stuck. Maths is not my strongest subject and I would really like to pass my exam this weekend.

Comment: What do you mean by university ?

Comment: Please be more specific about where you are stuck. The question is pretty explicit about what to do.

Comment: @ritwiksinha https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** :- $cos(A + B)+ cos(A-B)$ = $cosAcosB - sinAsinB + cosAcosB + sinAsinB$ = $2*cosAcosB$

**2.** :- $u = A+B, v= A-B$

$cos(u) + cos(v)$

$ = cos(A + B)+ cos(A-B) = 2*cos(A)cos(B) = 2*cos(\frac{A+B + A-B}{2})cos(\frac{A+B - A+B}{2})$

= $2*cos(\frac{u + v}{2})cos(\frac{u - v}{2})$

**3.** :- $cos(4x) + cos(x)$ = $2*cos(\frac{4x+x}{2})cos(\frac{4x-x}{2})$ = $2*cos(\frac{5x}{2})cos(\frac{3x}{2}) = 0$

$cos(\frac{5x}{2})$ = $cos(\frac{\pi}{2})$

$\frac{5x}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$

$x = \frac{\pi}{5}$

$x = 2\pi*n \pm \frac{\pi}{5}$ $or$
$x = 2\pi*n \pm \frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: Thank you , i still am confused about what im meant to do,but thank you for your help

Comment: @Daniel Then ask. whats is the confusion ?

Comment: Please note that MathJaX knows commands for certain standard formulae, such as $\sin\cos x$=`\sin\cos x`. If a function does not have a MathJaX command, then you can use the command `\operatorname` like this: $\operatorname{rang} f$=`\operatorname{rang} f`.

Comment: @gebruiker i did not know this when i wrote this answer. I know these commands now.

Answer (score 1):

Well do exactly what it says:

**" By using the addition formulae"**

Okay, first thing is to remember and remind ourselves what the addition formulae are.

There are $\sin(x + y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \sin(y)\cos(x)$

And $\cos(x + y) = \cos(x)\cos(y) - \sin(x)\sin(y)$

**" show that cos(A + B) + cos(A - B) = 2 cosAcosB"**

Okay $\cos(A + B) = \cos(A)\cos(B) - \sin(A)\sin(B)$

and  $\cos(A - B) = \cos(A)\cos(-B) - \sin(A)\sin(-B) = \cos(A)\cos(B) + \sin(A)\sin(B)$ (as $\cos(-B) = \cos(B)$ but $\sin(-B) = -\sin(B)$

So $\cos(A + B) + \cos(A - B) = \cos(A)\cos(B) - \sin(A)\sin(B)+\cos(A)\cos(B) + \sin(A)\sin(B) = 2\cos(A)\cos(B)$.

**": Setting u = A + B and v = A - B deduce that cos u + cos v = 2 cos (u + v)/ 2 x cos (u-v)/2 :"**

$\cos(u) + \cos(v) = \cos(A+B) + \cos(A-B) = 2\cos(A)\cos(B)$

Now $\frac{u+v}{2} = \frac{(A+B) + (A- B)}{2} = \frac{2A}2 = A$ and $\frac{u-v}{2} = \frac{(A+B) - (A- B)}{2} = \frac{2B}2 = B$

So $\cos(u) + \cos(v) =  2\cos(A)\cos(B)= 2\cos(\frac{u+v}{2})\cos(\frac{u-v}{2})$

**NOTE!!!!:  This is true of ALL u and v, even if we weren't given what A and B were in the first place!**

That's the point of this exercise.  For any $u$ and $v$ we can set $A = \frac{u+v}2$ and $B = \frac{u - v}2$ and it will be true that $u = A + B$ and $v = A - B$.

**Use this to ¯find all solutions of the equation cos 4x + cos x = 0:**

Okay $\cos(4x) + \cos(x) = 2\cos(\frac{4x + x}{2})\cos(\frac{4x - x}{2})$

$=2\cos{\frac{5x}2}\cos{\frac{3x}2} = 0$.

So $\cos{\frac{5x}2} = 0$ or $\cos{\frac{3x}2}=0$.

So how do we solve $\cos W = 0$?  Well, that means $W = \frac{\pm \pi}2 + 2k\pi$ where $k$ is some integer.

So the possible solutions are

$5x/2 = \frac{\pm \pi}2 + 2k\pi$

$5x = \pm\pi + 4k\pi$

$x = \frac{\pm \pi}{5} + \frac{4k}5\pi$.

Or

$3x/2 = \frac{\pm \pi}2 + 2k\pi$

$3x = \pm\pi + 4k\pi$

$x = \frac{\pm \pi}{3} + \frac{4k}3\pi$.

So $x = \{\frac{\pm \pi}{5} + \frac{4k}5\pi, \frac{\pm \pi}{3} + \frac{4k}3\pi\}$ are all the solutions.

Comment: great explanation.